# Выборка sqlite андроид

Tags: android

Доброго  времени  суток.
в бд  есть  строкас  тремя  полями: name; number; my;  есть  строка: вася; 34358; by:
как сделать выборку  чтобы  выдернуть  name=вася, number=34358; my=by???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cursor c = db.query("tablename", new String[] { "name", "number", "my" } , "name = ? AND number = ? AND my = ?" ,  new String[]{"вася", "34358", "by"}, null, null, null);
```